# GSON deserialized for type of Timestamp

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I want to deserialize timestamp by using gson in java.

```
// simple class what I want to serialize and deserialize 
public class TestTime {

    private Timestamp time;

}

// and I create gson and try to deserialize it
String body = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());        
TestTime data = gson.fromJson(body, TestTime .class);

// my test data in response body 
{"time": 1546476882}
```

However, I got this exception.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1546476882
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserializeToDate(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:107)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.DefaultDateTypeAdapter.deserialize(DefaultDateTypeAdapter.java:35)
    at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
```

How can I deserialize timestamp for long such as 1546476882?

Comment: what units is your timestamp in? It seems to be missing a few digits. 1546482609897 is a recent timestamp in milliseconds since unix epoch. you might need to register a type adapter as GSON doesn't know how to serialize a `Timestamp` from an integer (or long).

Answer (score 0):

As @johnheroy already commented, you need a [`TypeAdapter`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonTypeAdapter.html) for adapting
between [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) objects and `long` values (apparently you have seconds since 1970-01-01, the Unix epoch).

This adapter would be very simple

```
public class TimestampAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Timestamp> {

    @Override
    public Timestamp read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        return new Timestamp(in.nextLong() * 1000);  // convert seconds to milliseconds
    }

    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Timestamp timestamp) throws IOException {
        out.value(timestamp.getTime() / 1000);  // convert milliseconds to seconds
    }
}
```

You need to register this adapter with Gson like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(Timestamp.class, new TimestampAdapter())
        .create();
```